# Late updating function output in MATLAB - R2015b

Tags: matlab, function, slider, global-variables

I have the following code; this function is called from a parent script, and produces a GUI that allows the user to select a threshold parameter.

Unfortunately, the output parameter `threshold` is updated late.  For example, the first time the function is run, irrespective of how I use the slider, it reports `threshold` as being empty, even if I have set `thresh_final` to `0.9`.  The next time I run the function, it immediately updates `threshold` as `0.9`, before I can adjust `thresh_final`.  That is, when I run the function at time **t**, it outputs the value of `threshold` as the selected value of `thresh_final` at time **t-1**.

```
function threshold = threshold_choose(frames,prob_mat)

global thresh_final

f1  = figure('Visible','on','pos',[100,50,800,800]);
ax1 = axes('Units','Pixels');
    work_im = prob_mat(:,:,2);
    normali = max(max(work_im));
    work_im = work_im ./ normali;
    user_choose = work_im > 0.8 ; 
    demoImage = mat2gray(user_choose);
    imshow(demoImage)

sld = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
    'Min',0,'Max',1,'Value',0.8,...
    'Position', [200 50 300 20],...
    'Callback', @thresh_change);

function thresh = thresh_change(source,~)
    thresh = source.Value;
        figure(f1)
        user_choose = work_im > thresh ; 
        demoImage = mat2gray(user_choose);
        imshow(demoImage)
        thresh_final = thresh;

        closeing = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
        'String','Close GUI',...
        'Position',[700,20,80,80],...
        'Callback', @closeAll);

    end
    function closeAll(~,~)
        close all
    end
end
threshold = thresh_final;   
end
```

At the moment, to get around this bug, I can simply call the function, adjust the parameter, then close the GUI, and then call the function again, but close the GUI immediately, without adjusting the parameter, but this is not really practical.

I figure that this is because when I call the function, it runs the whole script, including the last line `threshold = thresh_final`, and then waits to run the nested functions until they are called, but I don't know how to get around this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that you are not defining `thresh_final` as a global in all your functions - but without seeing any code its impossible to tell.  Cut down on the words and show us some code.

Comment: Please construct a [mcve].